# Calculate probability of passing in an exam

Tags: probability

I need to calculate the probability of passing on an exam. Each exam chooses 30 random questions out of 5500 questions. If you miss more than three questions, you fail.

How can I calulate the probability of passing the exam?

I am able to get the number of aproved exams, the number of failed exams, how many times a question was correctly answered, and the number of unanswered questions.

If the user has awnsered most of the questions (a question can be awnsered more the once) correctly, the probability should be high and vice versa.

Comment: If your question is: "If I pick a random student, what is the probability that he will pass?" then the answer is just the number of students which passed divided by the total number of students who took the exam.

Comment: That is assuming that both the exam and student quality have stayed the same.

Comment: nop, it's not a random student, each user has a stats page, i want to calculate the probability based on the performce of the corrent user, this will give an idea to the user on how well he his prepered for the official exam since the questions are the same

Comment: Oh now I get what you want. This requires a more thorough answer. I will need some time.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: Can you get all the questions the user answered correctly? If so, you might be able to ignore the individual probability of each question, as any user could answer a question a hundred times incorrectly and get it on the one hundred first time. Assuming that once a student answers a question correctly he will get it correct on any future test, I might have a solution. If not, could you implement a forgetting curve? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve

Comment: yes i can, i have a table with all the values when the user fails a question i increment the "failed" column when the user answers a question correctly i increment the column "right", so in my project i only need to count how many rows there are with the column "right"  > 0 i am able to get this value easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to elaborate on AlgorithmsX' answer. Letting $N $ be the total number of questions to choose from (I.e. 5500) and $K $ the number of questions the user knows the answer to, then AlgorithmsX' answer explains how to calculate the probability that the exam is passed.

However, we do not know what $K$ is. Just assuming that the fraction of known questions $\frac{K}{N}$ is equal to the fraction of correctly answered questions, is not justified. Indeed, suppose that a student answers 45 out of 50 questions correctly. You can't just assume that he knows exactly 90 percent of the answers to the 5500 questions, he might just have gotten the questions he knew the answer to.

Assuming you **do** want to give feedback to a user who hasn't answered all 5500 questions, you need statistics. If you never had statistics, the following might feel backward. Let $m$ be the number of questions answered on the app during a 'test exam', $Y$ the number of correctly answered questions on the test exam. Then $Y$ too has a hypergeometric distribution.

$$
P(Y = k) = \frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{m-k}}{\binom{N}{m}} \\
P(Y \geq k) = \sum_{i=k}^{m} \frac{\binom{K}{i}\binom{N-K}{m-i}}{\binom{N}{m}}
$$

We want a conservative estimate for $K$. One way to find this is to pick the smallest value of $K$ for which the received value of $Y$ is not too improbable. "not too improbable" is subjective: statisticians often interpret this as "with probability at least 5%". I too will use this definition in what follows. Let $y$ be the received value of $Y$, then let $\hat{K}$ be the solution of

$$
P(Y \geq y) = \sum_{i=y}^{m} \frac{\binom{K}{i}\binom{N-K}{m-i}}{\binom{N}{m}} = 0.05
$$
rounded to the nearest integer. *Solving the above equation requires numerical methods: Google 'Secant method' or ask a new question if you do not know how to do this.*

You can now state with 95% confidence that the student knows the answer to at least $\hat{K}$ questions. You can then proceed to calculate the minimal probability of success using the method described before and with this $\hat{K}$ as $K$. Google 'confidence intervals' if you want to know more about the method used. This is a lot more complicated than the first answer, so take your time to look some things up and let me know if anything is unclear.

For the sake of completeness I want to point out that two implicit assertions were made:

1. Students can only get a question correct if they really know the answer. This assertion is false if the exam is multiple choice and a question can be marked correct because of a lucky guess. Extra calculations are needed to take this effect into account. For your app, I would suggest to encourage users to skip a question when they do not know the answer to avoid overestimating their knowledge because of lucky guesses.
2. The value of $K$ is fixed, I.e. students do not learn or forget. In practice, a good app should explain the user why an answer was wrong, thereby hopefully increasing $K$ during the test exam. On the other hand, knowledge can be forgotten. AlgorithmsX mentioned the Forgetting Curve in a comment before.

There is a lot of extra tweaks which can be done, but I think this answer covers the basics: use *statistics* to estimate the student's knowledge, then use *probability* to calculate their odds of succeeding.

Comment: thanks a lot i don't have a time now but i will take a closer look at this later

Comment: im just scraping the surface of this and im starting to understand it :D

Comment: i think i have a problem here, i need the **P(Y > k)** from the 2nd formula and i get the **K** in the third formula right? but if consider **N** as the total number of questions and **K**  the number of questions the user knows in the 2nd formula i will have to calculate the binomial,if **K** or **N** are big when i  calculate the factotial in the binomial i end up with a huge number if i consider the binomail **K k** if K = 5500 and m = 27 i will end up with `5500! /(5500-27)! 27!` this blows my calculator and my app, am i doing somthing wrong here? this seems to work with small numbers

Comment: You are right, you need to efficiently implement the calculation of these coefficients. As long as $m$ and $n$ are small, this is not so hard: Instead of calculating $5500!/(5500-27!)$, calculate $5500 \cdot 5499 \cdot \ldots \cdot 5474$. Your computer should be able to do this. If you only allow $m$ to take certain values, perhaps you might want to do all the calculations beforehand and store each solution in your app to increase speed.

Comment: If $m$ is big, then the method explained above might not save you. One workaround, like I said, is to let a powerful computer do the computations and just store the solutions in your app. If this doesn't work, you need to approximate. This is too delicate to explain in a comment, so Google 'approximating binomial coefficients', do some reading, then ask a new question if you need more help.

Comment: Better yet, learn to work with a specialised software package like R and it will automatically figure out the best ways to calculate these things.

Comment: it looks like i was calculating the probability of getting 28 right out of 20 known this was my problem i changed it and the problems disappeared, but i still need to learn how to solve the third formula

Comment: You cannot really 'solve' the equation, it's too hard for that. Instead, you use what's called numerical methods to approximate the answer. I suggested letting specialised software do this for you; if you want to program it yourself, I think the secant method will be quite reliable in this case, but you will have to do some research about that.

Answer (score 1):

This ain't no high school math here. What we need is a Hypergeometric Distribution. The probability that someone gets exactly $k$ out of $n$ questions on an exam with $N$ questions to choose from and the user got $K$ out of those $N$ questions is correct is
$$P(X=k)=\frac{{K \choose k} {N-K \choose n-k}}{ {N \choose n}}$$

The probability that the user got at least $k$ out of $n$ questions correct is

$$\sum_{i=k}^n\frac{{K \choose i} {N-K \choose n-i}}{ {N \choose n}}$$

In our case, $k=30-3=27$, $n=30$, and $N=5500$.

If the student had been through all the questions, this equation would be exact. This could be a problem if the student answered one question and got it right, but if the student answered a large enough question set, you could set $K=p*N$, where $p$ is the fraction of questions the user got right.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710226/probability-to-pass-the-exam-if-some-solutions-are-known?rq=1) is a related link from a similar question.

**Edit**
Someone pointed out that you need to make a confidence interval and do a whole bunch of sampling stuff. All you need to do to deal with that is pick a confidence level, use the total number of questions a person has been asked, and then calculate a confidence interval. What you then do is calculate the maximum and minimum values of $K$ and put that into the equation. The final probability will be within the two numbers you get with the confidence level you chose.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer i need to study a bit to understand this better i will aprove your question if not today tomorrow, once again thanks a lot for your time :D

Comment: This was a fun question.

Comment: I can't imagine that most students would answer more than 300 questions on the app, so you would often have to resort to $ p \ast N $ to approximate $ K $. But isn't this a bit awkward? You would want the probability of succes to increase when the number of answered questions (even those answered incorrectly) increases, but this needn't be the case if $ p $ fluctuates.

Comment: What I actually want to say is this: If someone answers 600 out of 900 questions correctly on the app, then he should have a higher probability of succeeding than someone who has answered 8 out of 10 questions correctly, because the app can more reliably say that the user knows about two thirds of the answers. Your approximate answer yields the opposite result. A more statistical approach is needed.

Comment: @Bib-lost The problem with that is you need to answer a large number of questions before you can conclusively say anything. If you only answer 8/10, then you cannout accurately predict how many questions he will get right. You will end up with some huge standard deviation and a low confidence.

Comment: That is my exact point: Your approach does not show the difference in confidence between 25/30 and 250/300. I will post a confidence based approach this evening (I.e. Within ten hours)