# Statistics to estimate the student's knowledge

Tags: probability, statistics

**Short Story**

I come from here, [Calculate probability of passing in an exam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932155/calculate-probability-of-passing-in-an-exam)

Im tring to calculte the probability to pass in the exam, knowing that the stundent knows $K$ out of $N$ questions, the exam as $m$ questions and the user needs to get at least $i$ questions right to pass.

$$
P(Y \geq k) = \sum_{i=k}^{m} \frac{\binom{K}{i}\binom{N-K}{m-i}}{\binom{N}{m}}
$$

I undertand how to do this, but i can't rely on this 100%, i need to estimate the user knowledge

**My Problem**

I been trying to figure this out but with no luck, i don't understand how to get the aproximate value of $K$

$$
P(Y \geq y) = \sum_{i=y}^{m} \frac{\binom{K}{i}\binom{N-K}{m-i}}{\binom{N}{m}} = 0.05
$$

I know i need to use numerical methods to find $K$ but i don't understand how, i know that there is software outhere that does this, but that's not an option for me

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear from what you wrote, but I think the situation is this.

There are a total of $N$ possible questions, and the student knows the answers to $K$ of them.  A random subset of $m$ questions will be chosen to form an exam, and the student needs to know the answers to at least $y$ of them to pass.  You know $N$, $m$ and $y$; given that the student passes with probability $0.05$, you want to find $K$.

As you said, to do this exactly would require solving

$$ \sum_{i=y}^m \dfrac{{K \choose i}{N-K \choose m-i}}{N \choose m} = 0.05 $$

However, if $N$ and $K$ are large, there is a useful approximation.  If we ignore the requirement to choose distinct questions and sample **with** repetition rather than without, it will make very little difference ($N$ being so large, the probability of choosing the same question more than once will be very small anyway).  The student has probability $p = K/N$ of getting any particular question right, and now the random variables for the different questions are independent, so the distribution of the number of correct answers is binomial with parameters $p$ and $m$.  You want to find $p$ such that $P(X \ge y) = 0.05$ for a binomial random variable with parameters $p$ and $m$.

This is still not easy to calculate by hand, so let's make a further approximation: if $m$ is large, by the De Moivre-Laplace theorem, $X$ is approximately normal with mean $\mu = mp$ and standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{mp(1-p)}$.  For
a normal random variable with that mean and standard deviation, 
$P(X \ge y) = 0.05$ if $y = \mu + 1.64485 \sigma$ (approximately).
Thus you want $p$ such that $$y = mp - 1.64485 \sqrt{mp(1-p)} \tag{1}$$
Subtract $mp$ from both sides and square, and you get a quadratic equation to solve for $p$:

$$ (m^2 + 2.70553 m) p^2 - (2 m y + 2.70553 m) p + y^2 = 0 $$

There will be two solutions to the quadratic: you want to check which one is between $0$ and $1$ and works in (1).

Comment: let me see if i got it right, i need to find $p$ for that i substitute the $y^2$ to $(mp - 1.64485 \sqrt{mp(1-p)})^2$ in the quadratic and i solve it to find a value of $p$ between $0$ and $1$, then i use the $p$ to get the $y$ and i use the value of $y$ in the hypergeometric destribution to get the $K$ right?

Comment: No, I was assuming $y$ was given.  You get the $p$ from solving the quadratic, and then you say $K \approx p N$.

Comment: i got lost here for a second, $y$ is the number of questions the user needs to get right and $m$  is the total number of questions, but $K$ will be a constant to all students $m$ is allways $30$ and $y$ is allways 27, the $N$ whitch is the total number of questions doens't change aswell so i will get the same $p$ everytime  or am i missing something here?

Comment: The other thing that's not changing is the $0.05$ which you explicitly stated.  If you changed that (i.e. different students have different probabilities of passing), you'd get different $K$.

Comment: but don't i need diferent values for $K$ this was what i understood from the Bib-lost anwser on my last question, i need to estimate the student nolage from the amount of questions he got right and use that to calculate the probability of succeeding, if i get $K$ using this method a student who awnsered 1 question right while studying has the same probability of passing as the student who awnsered all questions right, i think

Comment: You should ask the question you want answered, rather than a different one.

Comment: Sorry if i cause counfision, this was my question from the begining, i added the link from where my problems started Bib-lost told me that i needed to use this $$
P(Y \geq y) = \sum_{i=y}^{m} \frac{\binom{K}{i}\binom{N-K}{m-i}}{\binom{N}{m}} = 0.05
$$ bacause relying only on the destributuin wasn't enought, and he advised me if i didn't knew how to do this to ask a new question, that was what i did, im not an expert sorry for the misunderstanding